# Cloud has rectangle shadow

Tags: shadows

Cloud made by cloud generator has rectangle shadow:
[image]

Comment: make sure you have *receive transparent* checked for the map's material.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you have *Receive Transparent* checked for your map's material, if that is not checked the receiving material will only render shadows at full strength.

In the properties panel under the *Material* tab beneath the *Shadow* heading check the *Receive Transparent* check box.
[image: material settings with "receive transparent" highlighted]

[Receive Transparent](https://www.blender.org/manual/render/blender_render/materials/properties/shadows.html#shadow-receiving-object-material) (quoting from the manual)

> Allows this material to receive shadows whose intensity is modified by the transparency and color of the shadow-casting object

In the case of a smoke simulation, it will definitely will have intensity, or alpha less then one.

The image below is an example:
Without Receive Transparent on the left and with Receive Transparent checked on the right.
[image: example render with and without Receive Transparent]
 I changed the Receive Transparent on only the ground plane, the object casting the shadow does not need it checked unless it too will receive a transparent shadow.